# US convention different in spreadsheet functions (Libre, Google Sheets, etc.)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, libreoffice-calc

The Excel/Google-Sheets/LibreOffice function `DAYS360()` returns the number of days between two dates based on a 360-day year. 0 (default) is used for the US-based method and here are some examples

```
A = 30 Apr 2016, B = 29 Feb 2016, DAYS360(A, B) = -61
A = 29 Feb 2016, B = 30 Apr 2016, DAYS360(A, B) = 60
```

This seems ok according to the rules [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093042?hl=en)

But the Excel/Google-Sheets/LibreOffice function `YEARFRAC()` returns the number of years, including fractional years, between two dates using a specified day count convention. Even here 0 (default) uses US method, (US (NASD) 30/360) which I presumed will also be equal to the value of `number of days calculated by DAYS360 * the number of seconds in a day/number of seconds in 360 days`. The values in the sheets are as follows

```
A = 30 Apr 2016, B = 29 Feb 2016, YEARFRAC(A, B) = 0.1666666667
A = 29 Feb 2016, B = 30 Apr 2016, YEARFRAC(A, B) = 0.1666666667
```

Since it can be seen that the absolute value of the `DAYS360` is different by one, the `YEARFRAC` value is same and assumes 60 days according to the presumption made above, so are the US-based convention mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092989?hl=en) is the same as mentioned for `DAYS360`.

If not, what are the exact rules for this one, or is there some other problem?

**NOTE:** Tested these values on Google Sheets and Libre Office.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 0]

> ## **`DAYS360`** parameter 3:
>
> **0** indicates the US method - Under the US method, if start_date is the last day of a month, the day of month of start_date is changed to
>   30 for the purposes of the calculation. Furthermore if end_date is the
>   last day of a month and the day of the month of start_date is earlier
>   than the 30th, end_date is changed to the first day of the month
>   following end_date, otherwise the day of month of end_date is changed
>   to 30.
>
> **1** or any other value indicates the European method - Under the European method, any start_date or end_date that falls on the 31st of
>   a month has its day of month changed to 30.

---

> ## **`YEARFRAC`** parameter 3:
>
> **0** indicates US (NASD) 30/360 - This assumes 30 day months and 360 day
>   years as per the National Association of Securities Dealers standard,
>   and performs specific adjustments to entered dates which fall at the
>   end of months.
>
> **1** indicates Actual/Actual - This calculates based upon the actual
>   number of days between the specified dates, and the actual number of
>   days in the intervening years. Used for US Treasury Bonds and Bills,
>   but also the most relevant for non-financial use.
>
> **2** indicates Actual/360 - This calculates based on the actual number of
>   days between the specified dates, but assumes a 360 day year.
>
> **3** indicates Actual/365 - This calculates based on the actual number of
>   days between the specified dates, but assumes a 365 day year.
>
> **4** indicates European 30/360 - Similar to 0, this calculates based on a
>   30 day month and 360 day year, but adjusts end-of-month dates
>   according to European financial conventions.

Comment: So whats the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Although DAYS300 does not throw an error when reversing the order of the dates, the function is not prepared for that reversion.

Contrarily, when you reverse the order of dates, YEARFRAC swaps them before computing anything. That's why you always get a positive number.

If I were to use those functions in serious applications, I would program an error message if start date > end date.

Off-topic warning: YEARFRAC uses a different Actual/Actual convention from the Actual/Actual convention used by the other financial functions.